# Confused by Inheritance and EF Core

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn EF Core and I've got myself confused about how inheritance works with the code first implementation.  I've created by code first classes e.g.

Class 1 — `Card` (has a number of fields including an `ID`)

Class 2 — `SpecialCard` (inherits from `Card` but adds another field called `SpecialCardText`

EF Core migration has created a `Discriminator` column, but there isn't a `SpecialCardText` column in my Postgres DB.

I've tried to select from the EF using `SingleOrDefault` and I've got back the one row I added and than tried to pull the `SpecialCardText` value out and it returned it correct. However, what I can't see is where the data actually got stored in the DB. The `Discriminator` column has become `"SpecialCard"`, whilst other entires are simply `"Card"`.

Can someone explain how this works and where in the DB the actual values are stored.

Comment: Please post the code of your classes, to make the post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Since this is [table-per-hierarchy (TPH) pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance#conventions), it should be a column in the same table.